# Is there in R function for finding index of an array?

Tags: r, arrays, function, indexing

this is going to be a body of the particular Question.

which function we are using in array .

Answer (score 0):

You can find the index of the element by the functions
which() or match()

Example for using which():

```
# vector created
    v <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4,
        5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
    
    # which function is used
    # to get the index
    which(v == 5) # output is: 6
```

Example for using match():

```
# vector created
v <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4,
    5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

# match function is
# used to get the index
match( 5 , v )  # output is: 6
```

You can see [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-find-index-of-element-in-vector-in-r/) more information

Answer (score 0):

For a matrix or an array, set the argument `arr.ind = TRUE`:

```r
which(myarray == 5, arr.ind = TRUE)
```